# React - Jest testing - TypeError: refetch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm using a `useFocusEffect()` hook in my component, which uses `refetch` from `react-query`. Code is working fine in the app. Issue I'm facing is with unit testing. I'm using `Jest` and getting an error that `TypeError: refetch is not a function`.

I've defined a mock function `const refetchFunc = jest.fn();` and have provided it to `refetch` as a `mockReturnValue`, but still the error persist.

### App.js:

```
const { data, refetch } = useStudents(
  student?.id
);

useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    refetch();
  }, [refetch])
);
```

### Jest Test:

```
import { Home } from './Home';

jest.mock('hooks/Auth/useLoadAuthStudentsData', () => ({
  useLoadAuthStudentData: jest.fn()
}));

jest.mock('hooks/Student/useStudents', () => ({
  useStudents: jest.fn()
}));

jest.mock('@react-navigation/core', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/core'),
    useNavigation: jest.fn(() => ({}))
  };
});

const useLoadAuthStudentsData = userHook as ReturnType<typeof jest.fn>;
const useStudents = tasksHook as ReturnType<typeof jest.fn>;

const navContext = {
  isFocused: () => true,
  addListener: jest.fn(() => jest.fn())
};

const mockParams = {
  params: {
    studentId: 'studentId'
  }
};
  
  describe('Home', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const refetchFunc = jest.fn();
    useStudents.mockReturnValue({
      data: Student.deserializeAsList(studentsStub),
      isLoading: false,
      isSuccess: true,
      isError: false,
      refetch:refetchFunc
    });
    useLoadAuthStudentData.mockReturnValue({ data: studentStub });
  });

  const component = (
    <NavigationContext.Provider value={navContext}>
    <Home route={mockParams} navigation={{ goBack: jest.fn() }} />
    </NavigationContext.Provider>
  );

  it('should render app without error', () => {
    expect(render(component)).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

### Error:

```
● Home › should render screen without error

    TypeError: refetch is not a function

      54 |   useFocusEffect(
      55 |     React.useCallback(() => {
    > 56 |       refetch();
         |       ^
      57 |     }, [refetch])
      58 |   );
      59 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this for mocking your student hook  :

```
jest.mock('hooks/Student/useStudents', () => {

const data = {};

const refetch = jest.fn()

  return{
 useStudents:  jest.fn(() => return{ data:data,refetch:refetch })
}
 ,
});
```

Do lemme know if this works

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gaurav, same error unfortunately though.

Comment: its giving same error? :O

Comment: ive updated the answer @SJaka do check

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this way to mock react-query or any other hook response

```
const useStudentsMock = jest.mock('hooks/Student/useStudents');
useStudentsMock..mockImplementation(() => ({
      isLoading: false,
      data: [], // you mock data
      refetch: jest.fn()
}));
```